# What is the generic way to continue executing the code even after encountering the first failure in Selenium Python and Pytest?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

What is the generic way to continue executing the code even after encountering the first failure in Selenium Python and Pytest?

Expectation:
Execution should not be stopped after encountering the failure and the failed test cases should also be reported in the report as failed.

Comment: Please add more details: What exactly have you tried so far, what specific problems faced?

Comment: For reporting, I am using assertion that will take screenshot and attach to the report in case of failure. But, after encountering the first error, the execution is stopping (if assertion is used). To get rid of this, I used 'Try and Except'. In this, the execution will continue even if it encounters failure. But, it is not taking any screenshot in case of failure (code reached to except block)

Expectation: Is there any way that will not stop the code execution after encountering first failure. Also, it should take screenshot on failure and attach to report which should be sharable.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no code so, maybe soft assertions `pytest-soft-assertions` will help you. Soft assertions are assertions that do not terminate the test when they fail but their results are included in the test execution report. For more detail checkout the [Link](https://snyk.io/advisor/python/pytest-soft-assertions)

Comment: Can you provide me the link or documentation where pytest soft assertion has been used in a framework. It should keep all the failure executions, should take screenshot on failure and should update all these in the HTML report.

Comment: I think the given answer is what you asked in the question. For the usage of soft assertion in framework you can visit https://blog.testproject.io/2020/08/11/non-blocking-assertion-failures-with-pytest-check/ this might help you.

Comment: This link is throwing 404 error.

Comment: Check again, I have updated the link

Comment: But Pytest check and Pytest soft assertions are different.